# How do I call variables from other classes in Java?

Tags: java

I'm currently in the process of remaking one of the text-based RPG games I worked on using OOP. I was wondering how to call variables from other classes. Currently, my program is giving me an error because it cannot resolve the symbol "playerHealth" as it's in another class. The class I have below is the BattleSequence class and the variable I'd like to call "playerHealth" is in the Player class. How would I go about doing this?

```
public class BattleSequence {
    public static void main(String agrs[]) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the dungeon!");
   
        while (playerHealth > 0) {
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't show your other class here, but I'm assuming that you're trying to do something like:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public int playerHealth = 10; // Or some number
}

public class BattleSequence {
    public static void main(String agrs[]) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the dungeon!");
   
        while (playerHealth > 0) {
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

In order to do that, you'd have to actually create an instance of `SomeClass`:

```
public class BattleSequence {
    public static void main(String agrs[]) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the dungeon!");

        SomeClass myClass = new SomeClass();
   
        while (myClass.playerHealth > 0) {
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an analogy: suppose that you want to eat some chocolate chip cookies. You definitely cannot just look in the recipe and grab some - you actually have to use the recipe to make some cookies. I'm oversimplifying here a bit (for example, by ignoring static variables), but that's basically how classes work - classes by themselves don't really *do* anything. They're just a "recipe" for making objects. The variables in the class don't actually exist until you actually make the object.

A few quick notes: you may want to consider using [getters and setters](https://www.javatpoint.com/getter-and-setter-method-in-java-example) rather than accessing the field directly. Also, you'll obviously want to use more meaningful names than `SomeClass` and `myClass` like I used here. Pick something that makes sense for your program instead of the generic names I used.

Comment: This helps a lot thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can create a getter for your variable or make it static and access it like `<class-name>.playerHealth`

Comment: Should add, if you make the variable static then either you’re limited to one player or each player must have their own class. Either option is pretty bad.

Comment: no it's not bad, you will get new instance of <class-name> for every player, means that every player will have his own playerHealth value